# How to get a normal line function of a 3d function in algebraic form

Tags: calculus

I hope this isn't answered elsewhere. My searches haven't been productive in over a month's effort.
I have an arbitrary 3D surface z(x,y) = Axy+Bx+Cy+D. I'm trying to get a normal line to an arbitrary point on this surface (x0, y0, z0). All my searches lead to results that assume that my original function is in vector form. Not helpful. Ideally the line formula would be in parametric form L = (x0+Et, y0+Ft, z0+Gt). I have no problems with doing partial derivatives or similar operations; *it's the vector math that has been stopping me*. This is for a programming project.

Links to vector-based solutions to my problem are not helpful. For those that are complaining that my question is a possible duplicate please indicate EXACTLY how it duplicates another question. I've removed the vector-analysis tag to eliminate confusion if that helps.

I know the partial derivatives of my equation are:

$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = Ay+B$

$\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = Ax+C$

A, B, C, and D are scalar constants.

The solution I am looking for *parametric* description of line in 3-space:
{$x'=x_0+M_xt, $y'= y_0+M_y, $z'= z_0+M_z$}
Assume that *any* vector calculus links that you provide will be opaque to me. I do not know how to compute the gradient of a function for a given point for example. The one someone has provided so far as a possible solution depended on me knowing that particular step.

Comment: No. My actual problem is I have two surface functions z0 and z1. z0 is defined as I described in my original question. These are height functions who's input range is the unit square ((0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(0,0)). I'm trying to generate for a given set of inputs to z0 a parametric equation that is a normal to z0 and intersects z0 at t=0, and z1 at t=1. If I get the normal function determining the point of intersection with z1 is trivial,

Comment: If the linked question would have helped me then I would have said so. The actual answer someone gave was helpful, just incomplete according the the original question.

Comment: I would have loved to help you fill in the gap between the existing answers and what you need, and I was only trying to request more information so that I could address your question more accurately. It was not a "complaint", and I'm sorry if I made you feel attacked. Your question was lacking [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960), and I'm glad you have provided it now. Hopefully someone will now be able to answer the question to your satisfaction. Have a nice day.

Comment: You have a wonderful day yourself. Thanks for your efforts in trying to help. I did not see that the context of the question was necessary to answer it. I gave it later because I've found some people tend to get distracted from the original question and focused on the "why" of the question ("Why is this person asking this question?") rather than answering the question itself. They're trying to be helpful, but don't understand how the original querent might get frustrated.

Answer (score 1):

For a surface given by F(x,y,z)= 0, the gradient vector, $\nabla F= \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\vec{i}+ \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\vec{j}+ \frac{\partial F}{\partial z}\vec{k}$ is normal to the surface.

The line through point $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$, on the surface, normal to the surface is given by $x= x_0+ \frac{\partial F(x_0,y_0,z_0)}{\partial x}(x- x_0)$, $y= y_0+ \frac{\partial F(x_0,y_0,z_0)}{\partial y}(y- y_0)$, $x= z_0+ \frac{\partial F(x_0,y_0,z_0)}{\partial z}(z- z_0)$

Comment: I'm assuming you meant the third term to be "z=..." and not "x=". Sadly I don't have the reputation to actually give you a meaningful up vote. I figured the answer would be fairly simple. One quibble. I was looking for a single-variable, parametric form for the answer. I see terms like (x-x0) in the given answer. Can you clarify? t is a percentile value from 0 to 1 inclusive.